# search for the presence of two strings in oracle database in a clob column?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, clob

I have a clob column with a long string.

like "great job done today. good "

I want to retrieve all the records which has both the words great and good .

both the position is not fixed.

Comment: So do you want a solution which would match "My goodness! I didn't know old Jenkins read Greats at Oxford." ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what "which has both the words great and good " actually means.

If you mean you want to check if the string has both patterns of words, then it is simple as

```
where lower(col) like '%good%' AND lower(col) like '%great%'
```

If you mean they should contain true words good and great, then for simpler cases  something like should do

```
where ' ' || lower(col) || ' ' LIKE '% good %' AND ' ' || lower(col) || ' ' LIKE '% great %'
```

However, this will not match a sentence ending with the word and having a full stop. It gets lengthy if you want to simply use  `LIKE` to handle such scenarios.

`REGEXP` functions give more flexibility, but could be less performant.

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE ( s, '(^|\W)good(\W|$|\.)') AND REGEXP_LIKE ( s, '(^|\W)great(\W|$|\.)')
```

This searches for word boundaries, i.e. the word surrounded by non-word characters and start and end including an ending dot. If you want to ignore case, add `,'i'` as 3rd argument to it.

Comment: I think it is clear that the OP wants rows where the column contains both strings. So whatever approach we take a correct solution must be a Boolean `and` not an `or`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the basic logic you want:

```
where lower(col) like '%good%' and lower(col) like '%great%'
```

In clobs, you can't quite use `like`:

```
where dbms_lob.instr(col, 'good') and dbms_log.instr(col, 'great')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know if it works for you.

```
SELECT *
FROM clob_table
WHERE DBMS_LOB.INSTR(clob_text,'great')>0 
      AND DBMS_LOB.INSTR(clob_text,'good')>0;
```

Remember put the names of your table and columns.

Here my results,
[image]

[image: select * from clob_table;]

[image: SELECT * FROM clob_table WHERE DBMS_LOB.INSTR(clob_text,'great')>0 AND DBMS_LOB.INSTR(clob_text,'good')>0;]